# Error return from the pooledBin function (R package binGroup) depending on the method of confidence interval calculation

Tags: r, error-handling, package

Can anyone explain me, what is going wrong in the confidence interval estimation?

```
library(binGroup)
x1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,1)
m1 <- c(2  , 3 , 38 , 64 , 88, 113 ,250)
n1 <- c(1 , 1 , 1 , 2  ,1,  1, 56)
```

**Error:**

```
pooledBin(x=x1, m=m1, n=n1)
Error in if (abs(p.new - p.old) < tol) done <- 1 : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

**I do not get any error if I use the ci.method "mir":**

```
pooledBin(x=x1, m=m1, n=n1,ci.method = "mir")

PointEst    Lower    Upper 
       1e-04    0e+00    2e-04
```